# Why is my destructor getting called multiple times?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I have created a class and created vector of this class. I've put a `cerr` message in the destructor to see when it's called. I figured that the same destructor is getting called more than once. This is making me puzzled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class temp {
private:
    int _size = 1000;
    int _myBall [1000];
    int _id;
public:
    temp(int id) : _id(id) {}
    ~temp() {
        cerr << "destructor called. ID: " << _id << endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<temp> myvec;
    int total_count = 5;
    int count = total_count;
    for(int count = 0;count < total_count; count++) {
        cerr << "count: " << count << endl;
        myvec.push_back(temp(count));
    }

    myvec.clear();
    cerr << "Hello World" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The console output:

```
count: 0
destructor called. ID: 0
count: 1
destructor called. ID: 0
destructor called. ID: 1
count: 2
destructor called. ID: 0
destructor called. ID: 1
destructor called. ID: 2
count: 3
destructor called. ID: 0
destructor called. ID: 1
destructor called. ID: 2
destructor called. ID: 3
count: 4
destructor called. ID: 0
destructor called. ID: 1
destructor called. ID: 2
destructor called. ID: 3
destructor called. ID: 4
destructor called. ID: 0
destructor called. ID: 1
destructor called. ID: 2
destructor called. ID: 3
destructor called. ID: 4
```

Comment: Try a number bigger that `total_count = 5;`, you'll see that the reallocation doesn't happen every time you `push_back`, and it gets less common as the size increases (which is as it should be).

Comment: BTW, I recommend you to use `myvec.reserve(5)` and `myvec.emplace_back(count)`. Then all destructors will be [removed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7YYFlJ2STwkrCqnk) before `myvec.clear()`.

Comment: In your destructor, you are printing information that does not show what is going on.  If you would have printed the value of `this` instead of an `_id` in your destructor (and also printed `this` in the constructor), you would have seen that `this` referred to a different object.  What that different object is -- that is where you could have formulated as to what is going on, and ask "where does this different object come from?" instead of "why is my destructor being called multiple times?".

Comment: Add logging to the class's converting and copy constructors as well, that will give you a better idea of what is happening. `temp(int id) : _id(id) { cerr << "converting constructor called. " << this << " ID: " << _id << endl; } temp(const temp &src) : _id(src._id) { cerr << "copy constructor called. " << this << " ID: " << _id << endl; } ~temp() { cerr << "destructor called. " << this << " ID: " << _id << endl; }`

Answer (score 2):

The destructor is called due to the copying done every time the `std::vector` resizes.

`std::vector` re-allocates a pre-determined amount of memory once it's constructed (enough to hold some number of `temp` instances) - that's the `capacity`. Every time `push_back` is called, it evaluates whether it still has enough memory allocated to accommodate for the new instance. Once it is filled, it actually re-allocates another chunk of memory (enough to allocate a larger number of `temp` instances), and then copies (or moves, if possible) all the existing instances. These are the destructor calls you see logged.

If you know before-hand how many instances the vector is going to need to hold, you can `reserve` it to that amount.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at

```
myvec.push_back(temp(count));
```

Here you create a temporary `temp` object with `temp(count)`. This is then stored as a *copy* inside the vector. Then the temporary object is destructed.

The destruction of the temporary object is one case of the destructor being called.

Then as the vector dynamically resizes itself, it *copies* the contents into the new larger data memory. The object from the smaller data memory will then be destructed. Which of course leads to the destructor being called. And this resizing and copying could happen multiple times.

As for how the resizing algorithm of the vector works it's very implementation specific, but a common way is to resize for every `push_back` while the size is small and then reserve increasingly larger chunks as the size increases.

If you don't want this resizing and copying, then as long as you know the number of elements to be stored in the vector you can either set the specific size to begin with and use normal array indexing syntax to assign to the elements, or you can [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) space up-front.

Comment: For example, GCC seems to allocate twice the previous capacity each time it's needed: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Mh3VQCr4yYe7aPad

Comment: MSVC also does this